# Drag and drop files into Windows store app

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, windows-store-apps

I am trying to make a simple Windows store app where one of the basic functionalities are that you can just drop files into the app. Or at least that was the idea. I can't find any way to allow dropping files into my app. I have set AllowDrop on my elements but it won't listen when I drop files on the app (using split screen).

Is it possible to, say, drop a text file unto an open metro style app in Windows 8 (or 8.1) and how does one handle it in C#?

Comment: Cross-application D+D is not supported.

Comment: So if I make a text editor app then I cannot have people dropping text files into it? Is there a particular reason for this?